# Determine the value of a

Tags: linear-algebra

Please,this is the last problem that i need to solve:

Can you help me?

Determine the value of **a** such that the vectors **A** = (a, 4), **B** = (2,5) are parallel.

Comment: How is this related to the software program Mathematica? Maybe you wanted to post on math.SE instead?

Comment: @anderstood may you give me a link to go there?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=math.se

Comment: You want to solve $\frac{a}{2} = \frac{4}{5}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
Equate the direction ratios
$$\frac{a}{2} = \frac{4}{5}$$